# NetworkStream.Write gets stuck. What should I do after Write timeout?

Tags: c#, tcp, timeout, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm trying to send files from a TCPClient to a TCPListener with a 1000 byte buffer. The TCPClient is in one application "server" and the TCPListener is in another application "client". Both are running on localhost now when testing.
My problem is that the NetworkStream.Write method gets stuck (see the screenshots and code). I don't know why. After Googling I suspect that the socket buffers get full. So I set a WriteTimeout to 3000 ms to handle the problem. But I can't find a flush method that works in case full buffers is the problem. What should I do?

The server code (the one that gets stuck in NetworkStream.Write):

```
private void fetchThreadMethod(Object commandArgs)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
        byte[] comMessage = new byte[35];
        IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(localIP,1304);
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(localEP);
        client.Connect(localIP,1305);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("SERVER: Connected to client.");
        NetworkStream nStream = client.GetStream();
        client.NoDelay = true;
        client.Client.NoDelay = true;
        nStream.WriteTimeout = 3000;
        FileCollector fCollector = new FileCollector();
        String currUserVar = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
        fCollector.startFileCollector(currUserVar + "\\" + commandArgs);
        List<FileNode> collectedFiles = fCollector.getCollectedFiles();
        ulong byteCount = 0;
        FileStream fStream = null;

        foreach (FileNode fNode in collectedFiles)
        {
            String filePath = fNode.getFileName();
            try
            {
                fStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SERVER: Exception when opening file " + filePath + " with a FileStream.");
                continue;
            }

            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(fNode.getFileName());
            String fileHeaderStr = null;
            String fileName = fNode.getFileName().Split('\\').Last();
            ulong fileSize = (ulong) fInfo.Length;
            fileHeaderStr = "FHEAD" + fileName + "FNAME" + fileSize.ToString() + "FSIZE";
            byte[] fileHeaderStrBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileHeaderStr);
            byte[] fileHeader = new byte[400];
            for(int i = 0; i < fileHeaderStrBytes.Length; i++)
                fileHeader[i] = fileHeaderStrBytes[i];

            ulong sentBytesCount = 0;
            String comStr = String.Empty;
            byte readByte = 0;
            int readByteInt = 0;
            while(sentBytesCount < fileSize)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SERVER: Waiting for CLIENT_READY.");
                while (!comStr.Equals("CLIENT_READY"))
                {
                    nStream.Read(comMessage, 0, 35);
                    comStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(comMessage).Split(new String[] { "ENDC" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
                }
                Console.WriteLine("SERVER: Received CLIENT_READY.");
                if (sentBytesCount == 0)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 400; j++)
                        buffer[j] = fileHeader[j];
                    for(int k = 400; k < 1000; k++)
                    {
                        readByteInt = fStream.ReadByte();
                        if (readByteInt != -1)
                        {
                            readByte = Convert.ToByte(readByteInt);
                            buffer[k] = readByte;
                            sentBytesCount++;
                        }
                        else{
                            buffer[k] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for(int l = 0; l < 1000; l++)
                    {
                        readByteInt = fStream.ReadByte();
                        if (readByteInt != -1)
                        {
                            readByte = Convert.ToByte(readByteInt);
                            buffer[l] = readByte;
                            sentBytesCount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            buffer[l] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SERVER: Writing to network stream...");
                    // Gets stuck here! Timeout set to 3000 ms. Throws cought IOException.
                    nStream.Write(buffer, 0, 1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("SERVER: Wrote to network stream.");
                }catch(IOException ioe)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SERVER: Network stream write timed out.");
                    // ??? What should I do here? ???
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("SERVER: File sent:" + fileName);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("SERVER: All accessible files downloaded from " + (String) commandArgs);
    }
```

Client code, the one receiving the files waiting for the stuck server:

```
private void fetchFilesThreadMethod()
    {
        IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(localIP, 1305);
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localEP);
        listener.Start();
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream nStream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
        byte[] comMessage = new byte[35];
        byte[] comMessageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("CLIENT_READYENDC");
        for (int i = 0; i < comMessageBytes.Length; i++)
            comMessage[i] = comMessageBytes[i];

        ulong bytesRecCount = 0;
        ulong fileSize = 0;
        ulong bytesLeft = 0;
        String fileName = null;
        while (true)
        {
            nStream.Write(comMessage, 0, 35);
            Console.WriteLine("CLIENT: Sent CLIENT_READY.");
            nStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1000);
            byte[] headerBytes = new byte[400];
            for (int j = 0; j < 400; j++)
                headerBytes[j] = buffer[j];
            String headerStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(headerBytes);
            if (headerStr.Contains("FHEAD") || headerStr.Contains("FNAME") || headerStr.Contains("FSIZE"))
            {
                byte[] fileCont = new byte[600];
                for (int k = 400; k < 1000; k++)
                    fileCont[k-400] = buffer[k];
                fileName = headerStr.Split(new String[] { "FNAME" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
                fileName = fileName.Split(new String[] { "FHEAD" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last();
                String fileSizeStr = headerStr.Split(new String[] {"FSIZE"},StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
                fileSizeStr = fileSizeStr.Split(new String[] { "FNAME" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last();
                fileSize = Convert.ToUInt64(fileSizeStr);
                String dirPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\documents\\conquer_client_fetches";
                if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
                String filePath = dirPath + "\\" + fileName;
                fStream = new FileStream(filePath,FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write);

                if(fileSize < 600)
                {
                    fStream.Write(fileCont,0,(int) fileSize);
                    bytesRecCount = fileSize;
                    bytesLeft = fileSize - bytesRecCount;
                }
                else
                {
                    fStream.Write(fileCont, 0, 600);
                    bytesRecCount = 600;
                    bytesLeft = fileSize - bytesRecCount;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(bytesLeft < 1000)
                {
                    fStream.Write(buffer,0,(int) bytesLeft);
                    bytesRecCount += bytesLeft;
                    bytesLeft = fileSize - bytesRecCount;
                }else
                {
                    fStream.Write(buffer,0,1000);
                    bytesRecCount += 1000;
                    bytesLeft = fileSize - bytesRecCount;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

I get the following exception:

```
  System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at Conquer_server.Conquer_server.fetchThreadMethod(Object commandArgs) in C:\Users\tobb9\source\repos\Conquer_server\Conquer_server\Conquer_server.cs:line 241
-2146232800
Unable to write data to the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Comment: Note in MSDN that NetworkStream.Flush() does nothing yet. Reserved for future use.

Comment: What is the actual `IOException`? You are assuming timeout, however that isn't always the case, you need to look at the underlying `SocketException` to find the cause.

Comment: Ok I will add that and test run it again.

Comment: I printed the exception, hresult and exception code now. I edited my question and added it.

Comment: Next step is to open up a network profiler like Wireshark to see why the connection is being closed.

Comment: Ok I will install it and take a look. If you or any others might know or have a clue of what's causing this please comment or answer. Thanks.

Comment: You'll surely have to fix the fundamental bugs to get ahead, you can never ignore the return value of Read().  Sending "messages" across tcp always requires a protocol.  A simple one is transmitting the message length first so the receiver knows how often to call Read().

Comment: @RonBeyer how so I check this in Wireshark? I am not familiar with this program.

Comment: A tutorial on wireshark really isn't on topic here. You need to filter out the traffic in a capture to your ip/port and find the packet where the client disconnects/stops responding and look for errors.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will try.